# Co-occurrence count data sets

Tags: online-resources, datasets, language-models

I am looking for downloadable word co-occurrence matrices that were computed on large corpora. word2vec and GloVe have on their website downloadable word vectors, I am looking for something similar with raw word co-occurrence matrices.

http://clic.cimec.unitn.it/composes/toolkit/_downloads/demo.zip contains a co-occurrence matrix for nouns, verbs extracted from Wikipedia, BNC and ukWaC corpora, but the matrix was chopped: it only contains 1550 words. (1550 rows, 10000 columns)

Comment: Have you found any useful dataset Franck?

Answer (score 1):

I think http://www.collocates.info/ will have the data you need. Note, the full processed list is not free but is not outrageously expensive.

Comment: Thanks! So many NLP data sets put behind paywall by academic researchers...